# move an object follow a user-defined path on Android

Tags: android, algorithm, graphics, path

What algorithm or technique should I use to make an object follow the path that the user's drawing on the screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below example creates a PATH for displying TEXT on Circle Path:

```
// create a path
Path circle = new Path();
circle.addCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, Direction.CW);

// set the color and font size
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
paint.setTextSize(30);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);

// draw the text along the circle
canvas.drawTextOnPath(QUOTE, circle, 0, 30, paint);
```

You can refer full  [Example Here](http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2008/11/13/android-animation-101/)

And For Animation, There are mainly 4 Types of Animations comes up with Android SDK:

1. AlphaAnimation  – transparency changes
2. RotateAnimation – rotations
3. ScaleAnimation – growing or shrinking
4. TranslateAnimation – position changes

For CREATING ANIMATION SEQUENCES, refer  [Example Here](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343).

For ***Different Types of Animations Example*** such as Frame Animation (As in Flash), List Animation,etc. You can refer [Animations Types EXample here](http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/event/27/Introduction%20to%20Animation%20and%20OpenGL%20on%20the%20Android%20SDK%20Paper.pdf) .

Enjoy!!

Comment: can I use this on SurfaceView and instead of Circle I can change to complex path?

Answer (score 1):

I was just working on this in the last couple weeks for a game--how I did it was by getting each point from coordinates given by the touch event (when the user is drawing it to the screen) and then adding that to a list. I turned that list into a path to draw to the screen, and then just had the object update its location based on the list in the onDraw method for each frame.